# Why doesnt this javascript code work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function

```
function TxEncrypt(event)
{ //perform encryption of token data, then submit the form like normal

    //obtain public key and initial JSEncrypt object
    var txPubKey = txJ$(".zwitch_encryptionkey").val();
    var txEncrypter = new JSEncrypt();
    txEncrypter.setPublicKey(txPubKey);

    //get Data and encrypt it
    var txData = '{}';
    var txCryptData = '';
    if(txJ$(".zwitch_data").length > 1)
    { //if there are more than one element with this class, convert it to json string
        txData = txJ$(".zwitch_data").serializeObject();
        txCryptData = txEncrypter.encrypt(JSON.stringify(txData));
    }
    else
    {   //else, just encrypt the value
        txData = txJ$(".zwitch_data").val();
        txCryptData = txEncrypter.encrypt(txData);
    }


    dataString = txCryptData; // array?
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tokenize.php",
            data: {data : dataString}, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                returnedvalue = data;
                console.log(data); //alert isn't for debugging
            }
    });

    alert(dataString);
}
```

I could get the value of dataString.But the ajax parrt is not working.I have added the jquery library.But doesnt seem to work

Comment: What does "the ajax is not working" mean? Does the HTTP request not get made? How are you checking?

Comment: @Quentin The request is not getting made

Comment: @Quentin In the console.log Im suppose to get a text which is not coming..But the ajax code alone i working,without this function

Comment: If it works by itself, and the HTTP request isn't being made, then it must be erroring before it reaches that point. What error message is displayed in the JS console?

Comment: Im not getting any errors inside console.

Comment: How are you determining that the request is not being made?

Comment: When I used $.ajax request alone in a js file,the console.log showed the echoed contents of the tokenize,php file.But when I placed the ajax request inside the function of another javascript,which trigger at the time of a form submit,its not returning anything in the console

Comment: So the form is submitting and a new page is being loaded?

Comment: teh form is posted to this page itself.The page on which the form is made is a php file.The form action is given to this php only

Comment: I have the full script here http://www.datafilehost.com/d/a7a3ee93

Comment: @Quentin Please help out

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you are getting?

I think this should be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tokenize.php", //removed the dot
    .....
```